# Love and Sandwiches

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

*I'm from the Bay Area, but if I forget my order number when I make whichever one... then I'll be very rile-y!*

$$
\begin{array}{|c|} 
\hline \\ \bbox[purple]{\begin{array}{c}\\\quad\quad\huge\mathbb{Daily \  Specials}\quad\quad\\\\\end{array}} \\ \\ \begin{array}{ll} \large\star \ \textbf{Anti Italian} & \small\text{Hamburger, cheddar cheese, lettuce} \\ \large\star \ \textbf{Denver Nugget} & \small \text{Grass-fed beef, Weed from the Sea, Viper sauce} \\ \large\star \ \textbf{Deadly Gyro} & \small\text{Discolored lamb, bitter almonds, apple seeds} \\ \large\star \ \textbf{Urban Reuben} & \small\text{Roast beef, fresh cabbage, ten-grain bread} \\ \large\star \ \textbf{Puzzler's Slider} & \small\text{Smoked herring, Jigsaw Farms goat cheese, Nikoli secret sauce} \\\end{array} \\ \\ \bbox[gold]{\begin{array}{c}\\ \quad\quad\huge\mathbb{Create \ Your \ Own}\quad\quad\\ \\ \end{array}} \\ \tiny\textit{Choose from a wide variety of toppings, meats, and finishes!}\\ \begin{array}{l|l|l} \text{Aldehyde group}                      & \text{Famous constant}                       & \text{Recent}                      \\ \text{Artillery weapon}                    & \text{Formal dance}                          & \text{Robin Williams's daughter}    \\ \text{"Back to Back," for instance (var.)} & \text{Fried potato item}                     & \text{Robot from the Axiom}        \\ \text{Banner in the comics?}               & \text{Ger. broadcasting group}     & \text{Rolling in dough}   \\ \text{Barren}                              & \text{Greens, colloquially}                       & \text{SE site, shortly}                     \\ \text{Bygone musical genre of the 1970s}   & \text{"I } \heartsuit \text{" followers}                   & \text{Tallow}                      \\ \text{Common contraction}                  & \text{Kind of opportunity}                   & \text{Toilet, in America}          \\ \text{Coughed up the ball, on stat sheets}         & \text{Lad}                                   & \text{Top pick, slangly}           \\ \text{Course beginner?}                    & \text{Measure of economic growth, perhaps} & \text{Type of sauce}               \\ \text{Crow that's racist?}                 & \text{Methodology}                           & \text{UFC sport}                   \\ \text{Direction on a compass}                   & \text{NBA indiv. statistics}                        & \text{Unix documentation command}  \\ \text{Egyptian goddess of protection}      & \text{Not provided (abbr.)}                  & \text{US Representative Schiff}    \\
\text{Enoch, to Cain}                      & \text{Organization, briefly}               & \text{UV preceders?}               \\ \text{Equitable}                           & \text{Patriots, on scoreboards}              & \text{Video game rip}              \\ \text{Essential part of a map}             & \text{Popular NBC sitcom}                    & \text{Wrestler Orton}             \end{array} \\ \\ \hline \end{array}
$$

Answer is a **thematic phrase.**

---

Text transcript of the menu items (for copy-paste purposes)

```
| Anti Italian     | Hamburger, cheddar cheese, lettuce                |
| Denver Nugget    | Grass-fed beef, Weed from the Sea, Viper sauce    |
| Deadly Gyro      | Discolored lamb, bitter almonds, apple seeds      |
| Urban Reuben     | Roast beef, fresh cabbage, ten-grain bread        |
| Puzzler's Slider | Smoked herring, Jigsaw Farms cheese, Nikoli sauce |


| Aldehyde group                      | Famous constant                       | Recent                     |
| Artillery weapon                    | Formal dance                          | Robin Williams's daughter  |
| "Back to Back," for instance (var.) | Fried potato item                     | Robot from the Axiom       |
| Banner in the comics?               | Ger. broadcasting group               | Rolling in dough           |
| Barren                              | Greens, colloquially                  | SE site, shortly           |
| Bygone musical genre of the 1970s   | "I ♥" followers                       | Tallow                     |
| Common contraction                  | Kind of opportunity                   | Toilet, in America         |
| Coughed up the ball, on stat sheets | Lad                                   | Top pick, slangly          |
| Course beginner?                    | Measure of economic growth, perhaps   | Type of sauce              |
| Crow that's racist?                 | Methodology                           | UFC sport                  |
| Direction on a compass              | NBA indiv. statistics                 | Unix documentation command |
| Egyptian goddess of protection      | Not provided (abbr.)                  | US Representative Schiff   |
| Enoch, to Cain                      | Organization, briefly                 | UV preceders?              |
| Equitable                           | Patriots, on scoreboards              | Video game rip             |
| Essential part of a map             | Popular NBC sitcom                    | Wrestler Orton             |
```

---

**Hint 1 (minor spoiler):**

> The sandwiches you can create on your own come from a real-life shop clued by the title of this puzzle. It may also help to know that the puzzle creator is indeed from the Bay Area in California.

Comment: Toilet, in America or in Britain??

Comment: @OmegaKrypton More associated with America than British, yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first step is to realize:

> This puzzle is a reference to *Ike's Love and Sandwiches*, a sandwich chain in the western US with a *very* large menu.

The clues are ambiguous, but with the above they can be answered in a way that

> allows you to form sandwich names from the Ike's menu, by combining three ingredients together (as hinted by "[...] toppings, meats, and finishes!"). I used the [nutritional menu](http://www.loveandsandwiches.com/menu/nutritional.pdf) for this (warning: NSFW text, both there and in one clue answer below).

The clue answers:

> [image]
>
>  [image]
>
>  The numbers in the left column of the above image are the menu numbers of the formed sandwiches.

The next step:

> The "daily specials" sandwiches in the puzzle have strange names: if you read the first letter of the first word of each, and then the first letter of the second word of each, you get the cluephrase "ADD UP INGRS".
>
>  The ingredients of the "daily specials" each start with a different letter: conveniently, each of these letters is also the initial letter of one of the sandwiches created from the clues.

Finishing off the puzzle:

> Adding up the menu numbers of each of the triplets gives another valid menu number.
>
>  [image]
>  Taking the first letters of these resulting sandwiches gives the thematic phrase **I LIKE** -- appropriate both because of the creator's enjoyment of these sandwiches, and as a reference to the famous "I Like Ike" political slogan!

Comment: Wow, so many steps involved in this! Great solve, and great puzzle @PilsNot3! +1 all round...

Comment: Yes, you got the correct final phrase! In fact, rot13(lbh pna nyfb vafreg gung cuenfr evtug nsgre gur ryyvcfrf va gur synibegrkg gb pbzcyrgr gur fragrapr.) Well done!